# What determines Batman's movements when gliding?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

When you are pulling out of a dive, what factors determine whether or not you will pull upwards (thus gain some more height) or just glide forwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From personal experience, it will try to keep a somewhat parabolic pattern, sticking you back just a little lower than the height you originally dove from.  It seems that there's a sort of timeout on this though, and if you dive for too long you won't be able to reach the same height.

With a small amount of practice, it's pretty easy to find the "sweet spot" for how far you can dive and still come to the nearly the same height you were at before.

Comment: does your camera angle have any affect on how you perform?

Comment: Basically it's just how hard you move the analog stick.  Play around and you'll get the hang of it... pulling up all the way tends to cut your momentum short.